# Microsoft OneDrive File picker sends access Token and fileId to android

Tags: android, android-studio, onedrive, filepicker

Hi I m trying to integrate OneDrive with android using "com.microsoft.onedrivesdk:onedrive-picker-android:v2.0".

I need to get accessToken of OneDrive and once I pick a file in the one Drive, it should send that fileId.

I followed "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/android/?view=odsp-graph-online" this tutorial and I could integrate this com.microsoft.onedrivesdk:onedrive-picker-android:v2.0 to gradle. But stuck with next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after doing a big search, I could find a source provided by Microsoft team. 
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/onedrive/apiexplorer .

And we can take the accessToken for One drive using this command

oneDriveClient.authenticator.accountInfo.accessToken

And from the adapter of the source, I could filter the selected file id.